# How to change front end text in payment information section in Magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

[image]

Here is the snapshot for your reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: check in payment methods  for the text at admin > system > configuration > payment methods

Comment: I had verified already on before posting a question.

Comment: please add screenshot of configuration page

Comment: Added snapshot.

Comment: click on Atom payment at your list in screenshot. there you find.

Comment: You want this section before payment method section ?

Answer (score 0):

Click `Atom Payment` in your screenshot - is there a field there where this can be modified? If not, you'll need to search for this specific string in the code base and change it there.

Comment: I have verified in the code base like "/var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout" under this location with all the subdirectories, but couldn't find.

Comment: Aaron, any help please ?

Comment: Any help ?? really appreciate...

Comment: I just installed the Atom Payment gateway to check for you, and this text is not coming from that. You need to provide additional details with your question as to what else is installed alongside of the gateway. What are you trying to accomplish here? Why haven't you reached out to the developers of these extensions for help?

Comment: Finally got it, /.../checkout/onepage/payment.phtml

Comment: How did you find it?